# Regex pattern for key and value in Kotlin

Tags: regex, kotlin

I am try to split this String into key value pattern using regex

```
val x = "title=MyTitle, active=true, title2=MyTitle, Subtitle, new=false, title3=My Title#subtitle1"
```

I try using this formula

```
([\w]+)=(.*?)([\w]+)
```

the output is

```
title=MyTitle
active=true
title2=MyTitle
new=false
title3=My
```

Any clue to modified regex formula so the output become

```
title=MyTitle
active=true
title2=MyTitle, Subtitle
new=false
title3=My Title#subtitle1
```

Comment: Maybe something like: `([\w]+)=([^,]+(,(?!\s*\w+=)[^,]+))`? But it really depends on how complex your "MyTitle, Subtitle" is going to be. It's really hard to parse text where you have the separator that can end up in the values and there might not be a simple way that works 100% of the time.

Comment: Try it like this with 2 capturing groups `(\w+)=([\w+,]+(?:(?!\s\w+=)\s[#\w]+)*)(?:,|$)` See https://regex101.com/r/gWOcX8/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A look-ahead works pretty well

```
(\w+)=(.*?(?=,\s*\w+=|\s*$))
```

Breakdown

```
(              # group 1 (key)
  \w+          #   word characters
)              # end group 1
=              # equals sign
(              # group 2 (value)
  .*?          #   anything, non-greedy
  (?=          #   look-ahead ("followed by")...
    ,\s*       #     comma and spaces
    \w+=       #     word characters and an equals sign (the next key)
    |          #     or
    \s*$       #     spaces and the end of string
  )            #   end look-ahead
)              # end group 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use 2 capturing groups.

In the first group capture 1+ word chars. In the second group capture the words asserting what is on the right is not a whitespace char followed by a word and an equals sign.

```
(\w+)=([\w+,]+(?:(?!\s\w+=)\s[#\w]+)*)(?:,|$)
```

- `(\w+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ word chars
- `=` Match `=`
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `[\w+,]+` Match 1+ word chars or `,`
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `(?!\s\w+=)` Assert what is on the right is not a whitespace, 1+ word chars and `=`
    - `\s[#\w]+` Match a whitespace and 1+ word chars or `#`
  - `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?:,|$)` Match either `,` or assert the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gWOcX8/1/)

---

Or you might use a broader match for the value part using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) instead of matching the specified characters.

```
(\w+)=([^=\s]+(?:(?!\s\w+=)\s[^=\s,]+)*)(?:,|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gnKaeA/1)

Comment: not work perfectly still have (, ) on result..thanks for explanation

Comment: @kjuju2222 The comma at the end is a match, but does not occur in the capturing group. The groups in the regex101 demo are highlighted in green and red, and the match is in blue. The groups match your expected result.